# how to avoid sql injection with sql constants

Tags: php, sql, constants

I made it to where my constant is accepting input from users in sql but my value(1) is hard-coded ,i tried to use bindValue to protect this but bindValue doesnt work for constant ,  can this be hacked and explain how this could be done

```
$type = $_POST['type'] ; 


$update = $conn->prepare("UDPATE book SET $type = 1") ; 
$update->execute() ;
```

Comment: You could make an whitelist of allowed column names.

Comment: @novaSysEng thats not a duplicate, thats referring to values im referring to constants

Comment: whitelist sounds like the best option thanks roland

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Prepared Statements, please look at bindParam.
Also, have an array of columns that the user is allowed to edit.

```
$editable_columns = ['author', 'price'];
$type = $_POST['type'] ; 
if(!in_array($type, $editable_columns)) exit("you are not allowed to edit this column");

$update = $conn->prepare("UDPATE book SET :type = 1") ; 
$update->bindParam(':type', $type);
$update->execute() ;
```

more examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: i tried this this wont work because bindParam will format type as a string, so it will look this UPDATE book SET 'type' = 1

Comment: It will fetch the string value stored in `$type` do necessary filtering and put it at the place of `:type`. Did you try the solution I provided? If you have a bindParam that is not working please provide the code in question.

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UDPATE users SET ? = 1 WHERE username='aaron'' at line 1

Comment: its not going to work because its formating $type as PDO::PARAM_STR have you tested this?